# this.options in MutliModelExtensionBase is always empty

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Im trying to use the extensions on the viewer forge. I would like to add Markup3D but with the Extensions.Markup3D the default button don't work it don't show the list... 
So I also try to use PointCloudMarkupExtension which extends MultiModelExtensionBase. The this.option field is always empty in MultiModelExtenBase.

[screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVIH7.png)

Thanks you for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

If an extension expects some options (as in this case), you need to provide the options when instantiating the extension, for example:

```
viewer.loadExtension('Viewing.Extension.PointCloudMarkup', { react: myReactComponent });
```